# Another Mirror Mod Issue

Tags: vertices, mirror

This is kind of similar to another issue I had with the mirror mod, but this time my model that has the mod shows the mirrored version going through the main one. Even if I reposition the pivot point or 3D cursor so it's in the centre, it makes no difference, it never appears in the right place - opposite the main one.

It looks like my shoe model has far too many vertices and has made the file over 38Mb. Not sure of the best way to fix that. I've tried the Decimate modifier, but that ruins the model. :-\

https://www.dropbox.com/s/t5bjrr390g7131x/30_06_18.blend?dl=0

Comment: sorry I don't see where is the mirror problem, can you make a screenshot? About the shoe, yes it has too much edge loops, did you apply a subsurface modifier? anyway you could simplify with this method (ring selection, checker deselect, select edge loops, delete): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yptda_yKQIU

Comment: besides that, there was a solidify on the shoe, so it looks like both subsurface and solidify have been applied, which was not a good idea, but you can clean that manually... I don't think you'll have a good result with decimate or remesh

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the mirror mod. If you add it, it should show you what happens. Yeah, I added both a subsurface and solidify mod. I wanted to give it some thickness as well as detail.

Comment: About the mirror: you must apply the rotation of your object: ctrl A > Rotation. About the subsurface and solidify: you shouldn't have applied them, I think it's only useful sometimes when you want to export to some other softwares/game engines. Of course if you apply subsurf you will have a lot of vertices, it will be heavy and hard to simplify. Perhaps the easiest thing to do it is to rebuild a new shoe with retopology (create a new object and use snap to stick to the original shoe).

Comment: Thanks, guys. Much appreciated. I reverted to an earlier save and didn't apply the subsurf and solidify. Though that video on ring selection is very useful to know. :) Reverting to the old save and preventing that crazy amount of vertices actually helped with the mirror issue. Though I tested Ctrl, A and Rotation and that fixes it too. That's great to know! I've had that issue a few times. :D

Comment: great, I've synthesized the answer  ;)

Answer (score 1):

**1 - About the mirror:** you have to apply the Rotation of your object (crtl A > Apply Rotation)

**2 - About the mesh of your shoe:** you have too much useless edge loops, come back to an earlier version and don't apply the Subsurface and Solidify modifiers.

If impossible, Decimate won't give a good topology, so you can either:

- Simplify with the method described in this video (ring selection, checker deselect, select edge loops, delete): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yptda_yKQIU
- Or rebuild a new shoe with retopology (create a new object and use snap to stick the vertices to the original shoe)